# Return answer of inquirer prompt inside of another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, inquirer, inquirerjs

I have a function wherein I want to do some things with a class object selected by the user. I was thinking, I present them with some options, then after they select it, I use the string to identify the class object in an array of objects like so:

```
    function askAboutIt() {
  var questions = [{
    type: 'list',
    name: 'theList',
    message: "Message",
    choices: listArray
  }]

  inquirer.prompt(questions).then(answers => {
  var itemInQuestion = (answers['theList']);

   function isPicked(item) { 
    return item.name === itemInQuestion;
}

  var picked = (listArray.find(isPicked)); 
  })

}
```

Basically inside of some other function I would like to be able to call `askAboutIt()` and have it return `picked`. That way I could, for example, `console.log(askAboutIt()),` or maybe create a variable equal to `askAboutIt().someOtherPropertyofmyListArrayClass.`

I tried sticking a `return` in my inquirer function, but it returns as undefined, so then I thought, maybe I could stick an `await` outside of my `console.log`, but that's not getting the return either.

So then I tried using the `when` method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520423/is-there-a-way-to-use-previous-answers-in-inquirer-when-presenting-a-prompt), but then I got returned an error that "when is an unexpected identifier." Where exactly am I supposed to put the `when` method, or should I use something else entirely?

Comment: Have you tried any of the ideas you have in mind? This site is more for resolving specific issues rather than just writing code for people.

Comment: Good point, let me edit with my failed code ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I was able to do it by inverting my strategy. Instead of calling `askAboutIt()` in another function, I wrote another function `parentFunction(answer)` and gave it the parameter `answer`.

Then, inside `askAboutIt`, I called *that* function, like this:

```
 function askAboutIt() {
  var questions = [{
    type: 'list',
    name: 'theList',
    message: "Message",
    choices: listArray
  }]

  inquirer.prompt(questions).then(answers => {
  var itemInQuestion = (answers['theList']);

   function isPicked(item) { 
    return item.name === itemInQuestion;
}

  var picked = (listArray.find(isPicked)); 
  parentFunction(picked);
  })

}
```

In this way, I can use the answer of this question in another function.