# Using previous answer for the next question in inquirer

Tags: node.js, inquirer

I want to use the previous answer for the next question in inquirer, and this is my code:

```
const promptForMissingOptions = async (options) => {
  const questions = [];

  if (!options.name) {
    questions.push({
      type: "input",
      name: "name",
      message: "Name:",
    });
  }

  if (!options.file) {
    questions.push({
      type: "checkbox",
      name: "lots",
      message: "Select the categories:",
      pageSize: 30,
      choices: () => {
        const files = helpers.getFileNames();
        return Object.keys(files);
      },
    });
  }

  if (answers.lots) {
    questions.push({
      type: "checkbox",
      name: "files",
      message: "Select the files:",
      pageSize: 50,
      choices: () => {
        const choices = helpers.getFileNames();
        return Object.keys(
          Object.keys(x)
            .filter((key) => answers.lots.includes(key))
            .reduce((obj, key) => {
              obj[key] = x[key];
              return obj;
            }, {})
        ).reduce(
          (r, k) =>
            r.concat(
              new inquirer.Separator(
                chalk.underline.bold.bgMagenta(
                  "------------------------ " + k + " ------------------------"
                )
              ),
              choices[k]
            ),
          []
        );
      },
    });
  }

  const answers = await inquirer.prompt(questions);

  return {
    files: options.file ? [options.file] : answers.files,
    name: options.name || answers.name,
  };
};


let options = await promptForMissingOptions(options);
```

What I want to do here is to use the answer from the second question for the third question.

I tried the solution in here : [Is there a way to use previous answers in inquirer when presenting a prompt (inquirer v6)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520423/is-there-a-way-to-use-previous-answers-in-inquirer-when-presenting-a-prompt-inq)

Which didn't work for my case.

How can I solve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I get to your question, I would like to point out some optimisations to your example code that would help with this:

Where you currently using this:

```js
const questions = [];

if (!options.name) {
  questions.push({ question });
}
```

You could achieve the same with:

```js
const questions = [{
  type: "input",
  name: "name",
  message: "Name:",
  when: () => options.name,
}];
```

Two points from [the docs](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js#questions):

> **when**: (Function, Boolean) Receive the current user answers hash and should return `true` or `false` depending on whether or not this question should be asked. The value can also be a simple boolean.

The wording here is slightly misleading, but what it boils down to here is that when the function you assign to `when` is called, it gets the *current user answers* passed to it as the first argument, and ultimately your function must return either `true` or `false` to determine if it *should be shown* to the user.

> **choices**: (Array|Function) Choices array or a function returning a choices array. If defined as a function, the first parameter will be the current inquirer session answers. [...]

The description does go on to talk about possible answer value types, but the key takeaway here is the first function parameter: "the current inquirer session answers". At the point of Question 3, you have access to the answers from Question 2 *in there*.

> Also, just to throw in a little "personal opinion" here, I would *highly* recommend you move the logic that depends on `Object.keys()` **out** of your question `choices` handlers.. Rather pass in the *resulting* array of names to the question when you call it (i.e.: your current `options` argument). If any aspect of the structure changes, it will most likely do so somewhere else; if you keep this logic here, then all changes to that logic will require updates in both places in your code.

---

Now, to apply this concept to *your* example questions array, I'll use an example applying the above concepts for brevity.

```js
const promptForMissingOptions = async (options) => {
  const questions = [
    {
      type: "input",
      name: "name",
      message: "Name:",
      when: () => options.name,
    },
    {
      type: "checkbox",
      name: "lots",
      message: "Select the categories:",
      when: () => options.file,
      pageSize: 30,
      choices: () => options.categoryChoices,
    },
    {
      type: "checkbox",
      name: "files",
      message: "Select the files:",
      when: () => answers.lots.length,
      pageSize: 50,
      choices: (answers) => {
        const filteredList = [];
        const selectedCategories = answers.lots; // where the ID is the relevant question's "name".
        // now do your "filter" handling here..
        return filteredList;
      },
    },
  ];

  const answers = await inquirer.prompt(questions);

  return {
    files: options.file ? [options.file] : answers.files,
    name: options.name || answers.name,
  };
};

let options = await promptForMissingOptions(options);
```

I believe the code itself and the small comment in Question 3 should be clear enough here, but please do let me know whether or not this helps?

Answer (score 1):

`when` function received the prompt answers & return the `true` or `false` based on the response.

So in the optional question, just pass the `answers` into the `when` params.

```
const questions = [{
    name: 'REACT',
    message: 'Do you want to install React App?',
    type: 'confirm',
},
{
    name: 'EXPRESS',
    message: 'Do you want to install Express App?',
    type: 'confirm',
    when: (answers) => answers.REACT
}]

const answers = await inquirer.prompt(questions);
```